# Compression ratio for huffman code words

Tags: compression, huffman-code

So I have a question to use this data:

> A = 000, B = 001, C = 010, D = 011, E = 100, F = 101, G = 110, H = 111
>
> To compress this string: "AABACA"

Here is the method I used, but I'm not sure if I am right:

The uncompressed size would be 6 * 8, where 8 would be the number of bits per character assuming it is an ASCII character.

Therefore the ratio would be 48/18 = 2.666... = 3, where 18 is the number of bits in the compressed code: 000 000 001 000 010 000.

Would this method be correct?

Comment: Sure but that's really just using 3 bit symbols, as a consequence it's also a prefix code but in a trivial way.

Comment: In the question it assumes that these are the codes given, not ones that would be produced by a properly written huffman tree. So would this method be the correct way or is there another method i should be using related to this question?